# Apache: What could be stripping whitespace and otherwise altering .js files?

Tags: javascript, apache, emscripten

I've found that my ISP is altering my .js files... when I upload them they have lots of whitespace, but when I download them they have no whitespace and single quoted strings have become double-quoted. Clearly something is processing them, but what? How to find out what it is?

These changes sound harmless but they're actually causing Emscripten code to crash... I'd like the .js files to not be altered at all!

Comment: Tried contacting your ISP? The term you're looking for is *"minification"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whitespace removal and quote replacement are probably caused by some minifying process.

Probably your ISP have mod_pagespeed processing the files before they are being served, including the JS minification. If you have access to the apache conf files and vhost, check if the module is enabled and what are being executed.

More information at https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-minify

Comment: ISP denied using a minifier, yet one was quite obviously in use. But a day later, it's stopped happening. Maybe they were experimenting with one.

Comment: Yes, for sure. If the served file is different from the source file, something is processing it. Next time, collect the evidences and open a support ticket for the ISP to fix or at least give you the proper information.

If they refuse to do that, change ISP :)